# Nested YAML to nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I don't know how to  get a nested dictionary from a nested YAML file.

YAML file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KYTs.gif):

```
device1:
    device_type: cisco_ios
    ip: s1 
    username: admin
    password: 123456
    secret: 123456
    port: 22

device2:
    device_type: cisco_ios
    ip: s2
    username: admin
    password: 123456
    secret: 123456
    port: 22
```

Dictionary should look like this:

```
net_devices = {
    'device_1': {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': 's1',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': '123456',
        'secret': '123456',
        'port': 22,
    },
    'device_2': {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',       
        'ip': 's2',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': '123456',
        'secret': '123456',
        'port': 22,
    }
}
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: Have you had a look at the [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) module?

Answer (score 0):

Just install PyYAML https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/

Then :

```
import yaml
yaml_as_python_dict = yaml.load(yaml_as_string_or_bytes)
```

https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry for late reply. I was on holiday and last week tryed what you suggested. It helped me. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

[Install `ruamel.yaml` from pypi](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
with open('your_yaml_file.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
```

Contrary to the solution recommended by @glenfant:

- is safe with uncontrolled YAML input.
- it supports the latest YAML standard (version 1.2, published 2009)
- it is faster on most platforms (at least on macOS/Windows/Linux where wheels are available)

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of `ruamel.yaml`</sub>

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry for late reply. I was on holiday and I also tryed what you suggested compated to @glenfant proposal. It also works and I will decide later what to use. Thanks for your reply!